# Core data multithreading performance

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, core-data

I am developing an application that uses Core Data for internal storage. This application has the following functionalities :

1. Synchronize data with a server by downloading and parsing a large XML file then save the entries with core data.
2. Allow user to make fetches (large data fetches) and CRUD operations.

I have read through a lot and a lot of documentation that there are several patterns to follow in order to apply multithreading with Core Data :

1. Nested contexts : this patterns seems to have many performance issues (children contexts block ancestor when making fetches).
2. Use one main thread context and background worker contexts.
3. Use a single context (main thread context) and apply multithreading with GCD.

I tried the 3 mentioned approaches and i realized that 2 last ones work fine. However i am not sure if these approaches are correct when talking about performance.

Is there please a well known performant pattern to apply in order to make a robust application that implements the mentioned functionalities ?

Comment: have you seen magical record?

Comment: Yes i have but i am obliged to use Core Data directly without using any external library.

Comment: Have you evaluated a two stage stack, where the _"root context"_ is using a private queue and where the _"main context"_ is associated to the main thread (main queue) which uses the "root context" as it's parent. Any other additional contexts (if required) may use a private queue and either using the "main context" or the "root context" as its parent.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I tried a two stack stage by creating a "root context" (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType), a "main context"(NSPMainQueueConcurrencyType) having the "root context" as parent and "additional contexts" (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) having the "main context" as parent. This approach showed a lot of issues (i.e : when performing a large fetch within an "additional context", the "main context" is blocked and so the UI).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper check this link http://wbyoung.tumblr.com/post/27851725562/core-data-growing-pains . It says that the approach that you mentioned has many fallbacks.

Comment: I strongly suggest to at least try the suggested stack. I cannot reproduce the behavior examined by "wbyoung". More precisely, the parent thread will not be blocked if a child context executes a block at the same time.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rokridi,

In my Twitter iOS apps, Retweever and #chat, I use a simple two MOC model. All database insertions and deletions take place on a private concurrent `insertionMOC`. The main MOC merges through `-save:` notifications from the `insertionMOC` and during merge processing emits a custom UI update notification. This lets me work in a staged fashion. All tweets come in to the app are processed on the background and are presented to the UI when everything is done.

If you download the apps, #chat's engine has been modernized and is more efficient and more isolated from the main thread than Retweever's engine.

Anon,
Andrew

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is what i am intending to implement except that i am a little bit confused about UI refreshing. Do you rely on NSFetchedResultsController or do you perform fetches with private concurrent MOC. What am i supposed to do if i want to fetch a large amount of data ? Do i instantiate a private concurrent MOC each time i want to refresh my UI ?

Comment: I give you an example. Suppose that i am getting a large XML file from a server and after parsing it i save the entries with Core Data. When the process ends, the main MOC merges. Now suppose that i have to refresh some UI (TableView ...) or that i need to search some entries except that the search or the UI refresh operation could be heavy. Do i use the main MOC or i do that with another private concurrent MOC (worker MOC)? Right now i am using a single private concurrent MOC, a single main thread MOC and workers MOC (the workers MOC execute big fetches in order to update UI for example).

Comment: I use both fetched results controllers and custom controllers looking for merge notifications. iOS requires that you always update the UI on the main thread using the main MOC. The challenge to doing large updates in the background is that they are presented to the main thread as a large update too. This can take some time process.

Comment: I am having a problem with fetched results controller when merging the main MOC it with background MOCs. The merge results in blocking the UI when the merged data is too large.

Comment: Yes, whenever you do large amounts of work and merge to the main MOC you will block your UI. The answer? Do less work per save. I also queue up work on the main thread and do it at more appropriate times. Managing when you update is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends using separate context for each thread.

> The pattern recommended for concurrent programming with Core Data is
>   thread confinement: each thread must have its own entirely private
>   managed object context.   There are two possible ways to adopt the
>   pattern:      Create a separate managed object context for each thread
>   and share a single persistent store coordinator.      This is the
>   typically-recommended approach.      Create a separate managed object
>   context and persistent store coordinator for each thread.      This
>   approach provides for greater concurrency at the expense of greater
>   complexity (particularly if you need to communicate changes between
>   different contexts) and increased memory usage.

See the apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html)

Comment: I don't think this is the recommended approach anymore (namely, using *threads* in a Thread Confinement policy). I would suggest to use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` which are based on queues (and not threads), and `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

As per apple documentation use Thread Confinement to Support Concurrency 
Creating one managed object context per thread. It will make your life easy. This is for when you are parsing large data in background and also fetching data on main thread to display in UI.

About the merging issue there are some best ways to do them. 
Never pass objects between thread, but pass object ids to other thread if necessary and access them from that thread, for example when you are saving data by parsing xml you should save  them on current thread moc and get the ids of them, and pass to UI thread, In UI thread re fetch them.

You can also register for notification and when one moc will change you will get notified by the user info dictionary which will have updated objects, you can pass them to merge context method call.

Comment: Supposing that i am not using NSFetchResultsController, do i need to create a single managed object context (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType) ? Right now I am using three types of managed object context : one for the imported data, one for main thread and the other ones are workers (long fetches, insertions, delete, updates). In this case is the mains thread managed object context useful ?

Comment: It is not only depend weather we are using NSFetchResultController or not. In is always better to use seprate context for a thread. Using single context in different thread will invlove mutex lock to much, which will make your app slow, In your case if you are using one context for all thread and you start parsing big file your imported thread will obtain lock on your context, and other two thread have to wait. So its better you create different contexts for different threads. Creating too much contexts, is also a pain to maintain, you have to concern about the integrity of data.

Comment: In your case if worker thread have much work to do, then its better you create separate thread for main which will make your UI smooth.

Comment: So in this case i should create a context for the main thread, a context for synchronizing with the server and worker contexts for heavy operations. Am i correct ?